# Change the value of another class (Extension) with argument

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9

A function whose argument is used for Extension of another class is described.
I want to change the value of the UIView property (alpha) that exists in that function "at the button tap in another class".
However, this function can be changed at ViewDidLoad time.

How can I change the value when tapping buttons?
If possible please write the code.
ViewController Class

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var vHome: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var vSearch: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        selectRd(rd: 3) //This time can change calue of alpha.
    }
}

extension ViewController {

    func selectRd(rd reader:Int){

        var animateView:UIView!

        let animateVHome   = vHome
        let animateVSearch = vSearch

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, animations: {
            animateVHome.alpha   = 0.0
            animateVSearch.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: nil)

        switch reader {
        case 2:
            animateView = animateVHome
        case 3:
            animateView = animateVSearch
        default:
            break
        }

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.3, animations: {
            animateView.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Another Class

```
class Another{
    @objc func buttonTapped(sender : HeaderButton) {
        let vC = ViewController
        vC.selectRd(rd: 2) //This time can not!!
    }
}
```

Please comment if you can not understand the question.

Comment: the viewController with function selectRd() is already the rootview? Or it is subviewed into some other viewcontroller?

Comment: Thx for comment. Yeah already root.

Comment: Your instance of `Another` either needs to be provided with a reference to your `ViewController` instance or it needs to navigate the root view hierarchy to find it, or you could use `Notification`

Comment: Try passing instance of your controller to Another class and avoid creating new instance of view controller in buttons click event. Use already passes instance. Else you can try using delegate or NotificationCenter for accomplishing your task.

Comment: Maybe I finally understood what you wanted to say.
It entrusts processing of alpha value change to ViewController itself using delegate.
Isn't it?

Comment: I can not do this. This is unknown.

Comment: I just want to change the value from another class with button tapped event. F

Comment: It's coming to "case" of switch. yeah, i confirmed it with print(). But why... why can not change is only View'sProprty. Damn.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't access a function of a class if its currently active , as this will result in a crash  , so Add a var in viewControler

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var vHome: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var vSearch: UICollectionView!
var index:Int?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    selectRd(rd: self.index) //This time can change calue of alpha.
 }
}
```

..

```
class Another{
@objc func buttonTapped(sender : HeaderButton) {
    let vC = ViewController
    vC.index =  2 //This time can not!!
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, this could not be solved.
I confirmed whether the conditional branch itself is moving with "print" in each "case".
It seems that it reaches "case", but only property is not working.

Comment: is 
 the view controller with selectRd is shown when you want to change it

Comment: you may try using delegate to accomplish this or notification center